# Estimating total variation distance from a given distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

Given a known distribution supported on a finite set of $n$ elements with probabilities $p_1,…,p_n$ and an access to an unknown distribution $q$ is it known what is the number of samples from $q$ that is necessary and sufficient to estimate the total variation distance $||p−q||_{TV}$ up to an error $\epsilon$ with constant probability?

Answer (score 2):

[This reference](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.141.1698) demonstrates how to test that the distributions $p$ and $q$ have $||p-q||_{TV}\leq \max\left(\frac{\epsilon^2}{32\sqrt[3]{n}},\frac{\epsilon}{4\sqrt{n}}\right)$ with probability at least $1-\delta$ for your choices of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, with number of samples $O(n^{2/3}\epsilon^{-4}\log n)$.

In your case, you already know one of your distributions, which means you can do better, in general, even if you just execute their algorithm, and generate samples from $p$ given your knowledge of it.

The approach in that paper is to look at how many collisions (the event of sampling the same value twice) occur between $p$ and $q$, and compare that to the number that happen between $p$ and itself, as well as $q$ and itself.  Given that you know $p$, you could provide some of the collision rates directly from your knowledge of $p$.

HTH